# quitar boton minimizar messagebox python

Tags: python-3.x

Hola tal vez alguien sabe como quitar el boton de minimizar en un messagebox en python en ubuntu? en Windows no hay este problema ya que el messagebox no tiene boton minimizar solo cerrar, pero en Ubuntu el messagebox tiene boton minimizar, maximizar y cerra, gracias sus comentarios, saludos

Comment: No puedo hacer pruebas ni se si mi idea funcionará ya que no tengo Ubuntu. Además, puede que haya una solución mejor. Sin embargo, si no encuentras una solución mejor puedes crear tu propio toplevel, hacer eltoplevel.transient() (esto convierte al toplevel en una ventana sin el boton de minimizar y maximizar que siempre estará encima de la ventana padre). A ese toplevel puedes modificarlo y agregarle cosas de tal forma que funcione como un messagebox. Al menos esta idea funcionaría en Windows.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.